# django-haystack field boost - how exactly to use it?

Tags: django, boost, elasticsearch, django-haystack

All I know is that [this example](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boost.html#field-boost) boosts significance of the *title* field, at indexing time.

How exactly to use it with [`SearchQuerySet`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html)?
Which [`InputTypes`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/inputtypes.html) and operators (quoting, exclusion, OR) can be used, and how can they be mixed?
Which [field lookups](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#field-lookups) can be used and to what end?

I am using the ElasticSearch backend.
Example goal: boost entries whose title (not any other field) starts with (or at least contains) the query string.
General idea: `title__startswith=q` somehow combined with `content=Raw(q)`, so that we get all results of the latter, with boosting based on the former.

`filter(SQ(title__startswith=q) | SQ(content=Raw(q))` seems to have no effect on score.
Consecutive `filter(...)`s (or `&`) work weird: `title__startswith` allows things present in the title, even if not at the beginning, but filters out things absent there. Neither a real filter, nor exclusively a boost.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Whoosh as the back-end.

In a similar situation, after adding CharField or EdgeNgramField with boost=1.2, I noticed no change in the result list and in the result order.

I was able to approach my goal only by doubling the title field in the template file:

{{ object.title}}

{{ object.title}}

{{ object.body}}